# Inject a script reference in HTML files using ASP.NET Core middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm trying to inject a script reference into all HTML generated by an ASP.NET Core application, using middleware. My code is inspired by [this blog](https://www.billbogaiv.com/posts/using-aspnet-cores-middleware-to-modify-response-body) post and looks something like this:

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var newContent = string.Empty;
        var existingBody = context.Response.Body;

        using (var newBody = new MemoryStream())
        {
            context.Response.Body = newBody;

            try
            {
                await _next.Invoke(context);
            }
            finally
            {
                context.Response.Body = existingBody;
            }

            newBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            newContent = new StreamReader(newBody).ReadToEnd();

            if (context.Response.ContentType.StartsWith("text/html"))
            {
                newContent = newContent.Replace("</body", "<script src=\"my-reference-here\"></script></body");
            }

            await context.Response.WriteAsync(newContent);
        }
    }
}
```

The main challenge here is that the middleware run for all requests to the server, including CSS, javascripts, favicons, etc. I would like it to run for HTML output only, since the code above causes problems for some file types and since I don't want to write all responses two times.

Any way of doing this in a better way? I've logged at `MapWhen`, but it doesn't seem to support looking at the content-type of the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally recommend you *not* to implement this as a middleware. As you can see from your own implementation, you are reading the whole response into memory just to be able to perform some replacement on it. That’s really inefficient and prevents you from streaming the response. [BrowserLink](https://github.com/aspnet/BrowserLink) does this by [modifying the stream as it happens](https://github.com/aspnet/BrowserLink/blob/2.1.1/src/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink/BrowserLinkMiddleWare.cs#L95) so that would be more effcient.

But you should consider moving this logic into MVC. Of course this assumes that you do not need to modify static file content. But within MVC, you could write a [result filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#result-filters) that only gets executed when a `ViewResult` is being produced (i.e. when a MVC view gets rendered). And in that filter, you could then modify the view result to set some parameters to inject that script.

And inside of MVC, I would just add a tag helper or some section into your layout in which you could then render your script tag. That way, you would have maintain full control over the layout and integrate this nicely with MVC.

That being said, to avoid running your middleware for unrelated responses, of course you could also simply move your check of `Response.ContentType` further up, so you don’t actually read the response into a memory stream for responses that you do not need to modify.

Comment: You're right. Too many things can go wrong injecting the script through middleware and it's inefficient as you mention. I've implemented a tag helper that inserts the script. It requires a bit of manual work, but I believe it's worth it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use sections in your views. Just implement this in your layout:

```
@RenderSection("BottomScripts", required: false)
```

And then in your views you can use something like this:

```
@section BottomScripts {
 @if (Model.NeedThisScript)
 {
  await Html.RenderPartialAsync("PartialWithYourScripts");
 }
}
```